# generate firebase queryfn from array with AngularFirestore in angular

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to get data from Firebase using AngularFirestore (package @angular/fire/firestore) with queryfn . but i could not found any tutorials

here is the code i had tried, but not working to filter data from firebase

```
getFirebaseData(collection:any):Observable<any>{
      let filter:any[] = [
          {field:field1, operator:"==", value:"value1"},
          {field:field2, operator:"==", value:"value2"}]

      return this.firestore.collection(collection, 
             ref=>{
               
               filter.map{fltr=>{
                  return ref.where(fltr.field, fltr.operator, fltr.value)
               }
               return ref
            }).snapshotChanges()

      
}
```

So, how can i filter firebase data from array

i had try to find the solution, but not found anything, I would be glad for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md) in the AngularFire repository there are some examples. and on the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) it is explained how to do composite queries.

here I add a quick example with composite queries over a collection:

```
        afs.collection('<CollectionID>', ref => {
          let query : firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
          { query = query.where('field1', '==', value1) };
          { query = query.where('field2', '==', value2) };
          return query;
        }).valueChanges()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but when i try it i got FirebaseError: The query requires an index

Comment: but i try other data field, is working, i think error is from firebase... ,, thanks for help @soni